# Time-Invariant System

Tags: homework

[image]

I don't know if I'm missing a step or a (mathematical) concept is unclear but when I apply time-invariance property: 
1) delay original output y(t) by t0, check resulting expression y(t - t0)
2) delay original input x(t) by t0 i.e. x(t - t0), check resulting expression y'(t)

If y(t - t0) = y'(t), then the system is time invariant. Upon performing these operations, I came down the conclusion that the system is time invariant which is not the right answer.

Comment: Your input expression is \$x(1 - t)\$.  If you just let \$u(t) = x(1 - t)\$, is that time-invariant?  Does \$u(t - t_0) = x(1 - (t - t_0))\$ for all \$t\$ and \$t_0\$?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is
$$ y(t) = (3-2j)x(1-t)$$

> 1) delay original output y(t) by t0, check resulting expression y(t - t0)

The first step I suggest is not needed but prevents mixing up variable 't' when the given expression is more complex and helps using the correct sign (it will be **+** t0 later on); first rewrite the original expression with a different time variable, e.g. u:
$$ y(u) = (3-2j)x(1-u)$$

In order to get the delayed output y(t-t0), you need to substitute \$u=t-t0\$

$$ y(u)|_{u=t-t0} = (3-2j)x(1-u)|_{u=t-t0} $$
$$ y(t-t0) = (3-2j)x(1-(t-t0))$$
$$ y(t-t0) = (3-2j)x(1-t+t0))$$

> 2) delay original input x(t) by t0 i.e. x(t - t0), check resulting expression y'(t)

The expression for y'(t) (the ouput that is generated by the **delayed input**) is thus:

$$ y'(t) = (3-2j)x_{delayed}(1-t)$$

Now, I suggest to first rewrite the **delayed input** with a different time variable, so:

$$ x_{delayed}(u) = x(u-t0) $$

and substitute it in y'(t) above:

$$ y'(t) = (3-2j)x_{delayed}(1-t)|_{x_{delayed}(u) = x(u-t0)}$$

$$ y'(t) = (3-2j)x(1-t-t0)$$

Now, you can see that the delayed output \$y(t-t0)\$ is not equal to the output y'(t) generated by a delayed input

$$ y(t-t0) \neq y'(t)$$

---

- So, for the **delayed output** you rewrite the **original** expression with a different time variable and substitue (t-t0) for that variable.
  (You can also directly substitute t=(t-t0), but doing in steps may prevent errors)
- For the output y'(t) generated by the **delayed input** x(t-t0) you rewrite the **delayed input** with a different time variable and substitute this in y'(t)

Answer (score 0):

Let \$3-2j=A\$ (a constant) ...doesn't affect the answer
$$y(t)=Ax(1-t)$$
To check that time-invariance property hold for above equation, Let \$x_1(t)\$ be an arbitary input to the system , and let
\begin{equation}
y_1(t)=Ax_1(1-t)
\end{equation}
be the corresponding output. Then consider a second input obtained by shifting \$x_1(t)\$ in time by \$t_0\$: 
\begin{equation}
x_2(t)=x_1(t-t_0)
\end{equation}
The output corresponding to this input is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_2(t)&=Ax_2(1-t)\\
&=Ax_1(1-t-t_0)
&=y_1(t+t_0)\neq y_1(t-t_0)
\end{split}
\end{equation}hence the system is time varying.